# How to unit test if/else statement in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

application.yml

```
feature:
  toggles:
    checksLoginAndRegistration: true
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Value("${feature.toggles.checksLoginAndRegistration}")
private boolean checksLoginAndRegistration;
    
private void validateLicense(LicenseData licenseData,RegistrationData registrationData) {
        validateAddress(registrationData, UserRepository::logWarning);
        if(checksLoginAndRegistration) {
            try {
                service.validateRegistration(registrationData);
            } catch (RgValidationException rgValidationException) {
                throw new AccountRegulationBlockedException(registrationData.username());
            }
        }
    }
```

So I need to test if checksLoginAndRegistration=true or if its false.

Comment: You can use `ReflectionTestUtils` in your test to set `checksLoginAndRegistration` value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will require small refactoring.

Example with constructor injection:

```java
public class LogingChecker{
  private final boolean checksLoginAndRegistration;
  public LogingChecker(@Value("${feature.toggles.checksLoginAndRegistration}") boolean checksLoginAndRegistration){
    this.checksLoginAndRegistration = checksLoginAndRegistration;
  }
...

}
```

after that you can easily instantiate your class for the tests with proper flag

If there are a lot of flags you can use setter injection instead of constructor injection.
If you decide that all these flags can be grouped in separate class then create for instance LoginProperties class with all flags that can be used and use constructor injection(LoginProperties should be component).

Another approach that will not require any refactoring but not good IMO: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html

You can manipulate the flag with this command:

```java
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(nameOfYourService, "checksLoginAndRegistration", true);
```

Comment: can you please write example of test

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test the value of `checksLoginAndRegistration` then you can expose a getter for it and write test cases for it.

Instead of this, I will write two test cases. Here is what I'd do:

1. I can set the flag true in the first test case, then set it false in the second test case.
2. Invoke this method that will set the corresponding state in the respective entity like UserStatus -> REGISTERED.
3. Assert the expected entity state like UserStatus in both cases.

Comment: can you please wite in code i would appreciate